# Overriding Dart methods with Generics arguments

Tags: oop, generics, dart, polymorphism

I have this case where I am extending from a super class with methods being typed using Generics as the following:

### Models

```dart
abstract class SuperClass { 

   //.....
}


class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  int a;
  int b;
  String c;
  //....
}
```

### Controllers

```dart
abstract class A {
   T getDoc<T extends SuperClass>(T doc);
} 

class B extends A {
   T getDoc<T extends SubClass>(T doc) {     //<================ Error
       //....
    }       
}
```

Basically class `B` will only deal with a `SubClass` model and any class that extends it. Extending `SuperClass` is not enough. It's a way to enforce the type usage. I could add a helper function that will check the type for each method within class `B` (`doc is SubClass`) but seems like a lot repetition.

But the above architecture fails when overriding the method `getDoc` in class B saying that it isn't a valid override although `SubClass` is a `SuperClass`. How can I achieve something like this? Or is there a better way of doing it? Appreciate any pointers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally a found a way :)

So I wanted the class `B`'s methods to accept exclusively types that extend `SubClass`, but class `A` method's signature expects parameters extending class `SuperClass`.

To go about this I did the following:

### Models

```dart
abstract class SuperClass { 

   //.....
}


class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  int a;
  int b;
  String c;
  //....
}
```

### Controllers

```dart
abstract class A<K extends SuperClass> {
   T getDoc<T extends K>(T doc);
} 

class B extends A<SubClass> {
   T getDoc<T extends SubClass>(T doc) {     
          //.......
    }       
}
```

Comment: Please share a pastebin of your code, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I found the error. Is because my abstract class A, extends from StatefulWidget and implement the state class. 
class _AState extends State<SliverListView>
Now I need fix this

Answer (score 3):

can you use covariant modifier.

In your example:

```
abstract class A {
   T getDoc<T extends SuperClass>(covariant T doc);
}
```

Check: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/covariant-overrides.md

Answer (score 0):

You can not narrow the generic type argument. Class `B` guaranties (by extending class `A`), that it will/can handle all type arguments (and sub types!), that class `A` can handle. Consider the following situation:

```
class OtherSubClass extends SuperClass {
  //....
}

void main() {
  var b = B();
  b.getDoc(OtherSubClass());
}
```

What would you expect to happen? Class `B` is not able to handle objects of type `OtherSubClass`, so it breaks the contract with class `A`.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the class architecture and elaborated more on what I'm trying to achieve.